# Multiple transactions same wallet nonce problem

Tags: python, nft, web3py

Basically, I have a telegram bot, users can Mint nfts with it, the minting command is sent to my python code which uses the same wallet to mint nfts.

There is hundreds of users using the bot, so multiple transactions at the same time are bound to happen.

I made a test, sent 10 minting transactions at the same time, every time it fails after some successful ones. First problem was nonce too low.

I fixed it by implementing this code:

```
  nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount("wallet")
```

then implemented it in the build transaction, but that caused this error to occur:

> ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'ALREADY_EXISTS: already known'}

What's the solution to fix this? Knowing that multiple pending transactions can occur.

I tried doing it with a normal counter instead and add +1 to counter in each tx, this happened:

> ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'INTERNAL_ERROR: could not replace existing tx'}

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because
[Eth.get_transaction_count](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.get_transaction_count) only returns the **confirmed** transactions. So two transactions sent at the same time -before any block confirmation- will have the same nonce and clash with each other.

The default behavior returns transactions from the `latest` block, not including `pending` transactions.

It doesn't seem that [web3.py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.get_transaction_count) supports counting pending transactions:

> Eth.get_transaction_count(account, block_identifier=web3.eth.default_block)
>
> Delegates to eth_getTransactionCount RPC Method
>
> Returns the number of transactions that have been sent from account as of the block specified by block_identifier.

so you might have to send an RPC call outside of web3.py.

Here is the RPC call doc: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_gettransactioncount.